# Configure WiFi router with HTTP proxy settings?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

I have a web proxy account to a remote network over the internet. It works fine for macOS etc… where I can just open up the network settings and enter the http proxy settings, and then all http and https traffic will be routed through the server set up in that setting.

Now I have a few other (non-computer) devices (TVs, Roku:s, etc) that do not have http proxy settings, but I'd like to route the traffic of those devices through that proxy anyway. How can I do this? Is there any kind of WiFi router maker that allows setting up http proxy settings? So I can just connect any device to that wifi and they automatically/invisibly get their http traffic routed through that proxy server?

Or is there any other way of solving this? I've been thinking of having the Macintosh act as a hotspot and share the proxy setting through the hotspot, but have been seeing similar questions and the answers seem to suggest that it's not possible. And TVs in particular don't seem to be able to pick up the hotspot of a Macintosh anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem to solve, bit there are many ways that could work.

SOHO routers don't have this support, so you may either need to flash it with dd-wrt or similar or use enterprise grade stuff.

Your exact setup and constraints are unclear, but by far the easiest option if its available to you is to set up a VPN between the router and a VPN providet on the Internet with the same level of access that the Web Proxy has.

If thats not an option you can set up transparent proxying for HTTP. (Doing this for HTTPS is much more difficult and may not be possible due to self signed certs/can requirements). Google "Linux transparent proxy" if this is an option.

Other solutions can attempt to configure browsers to proxy via network settings, but these mechanisms are varied and it would seem you are unlikely to get far with a diverse array of hardware.

I observe your comment about using the MAC as a hotspot. This is unlikely to work, as proxying works at a browser level while hotspotting works at the IP (and lower) level.

Comment: As I've been using an aging Airport Express since the beginning of times I am prepared to get a new WiFi router anyway. If there were any such router or equipment that would be able to pull this off I probably would buy it, granted it's reasonable in a home environment and wouldn't attract attention from household members (price). I agree that routers and such seem to be working at a much lower level than http proxies which seems to suggest that routers aren't going to be helpful no matter the price.

Comment: If you are looking for an ethernet router, get anything that suits your budget that you can flash dd-wrt on - https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/   (I like ASUS equipment myself).  Note that this won't in itself solve your problem DD-WRT won't magically do what you want, but it will give you the tools and interfaces you need to do it - whether it is acting as a VPN client or a transparent proxy.  (DD-WRT is effectively imbedded Linux targetted at routers, and has both a web interface for typical users and powerful shell access )

Comment: With respect of routers and HTTP proxies, its not the proxying thats the issue - its the *transparent* proxying.  When you transparently proxy, your proxy server says to the client "I am the server", and then fetches the page from the server.  Of-course, this is identical to a Man-In-The-Middle attack, and HTTPS is designed to thwart it.   In order to overcome this obstacle you need to create your own CA (Certificate Authority), **but this needs to be accepted by the browser**.    Using a VPN means no MITM and can work seemlessly but requires an appropriately located VPN server.